FMX CPP String Grid Assign Columns to database fields in code
I am using Rad Studio 12.2 C++ Builder and am new to FMX TStringGrid and its live bindings and want to know how I can assign a column created at runtime to a specific field in the database binding.  I have done this in VCL, but this is much simpler, just setting the column FieldName to the desired field.  FMX has no such parameter and I cannot find an example where the column is assigned at run time.
I have seen the example Connect Database to string grid with code.
However, this only has two fields which are simply assigned to the first two columns and does not tell me how the columns are assigned to the database fields.
I have a database with multiple fields and only want a subset of these fields to display at runtime.  I also wish to create the columns dynamically depending upon the view selected such that only required columns are visible.
I can bind the grid to the database and I can clear and create columns in the grid, but I do not know how to assign a created column to a bound field. Would really appreciate being pointed to a c++ example if possible as my project is in builder rather than Delphi.
